# SSMS. Anyway to connect via AWS session-manager to an mssql instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, linux, ubuntu, aws

I have a sqlserver (express) instance running on an ubuntu server ec2 instance. This is on an AWS private subnet so I cannot just open port 1433 for sql access. We use AWS session manager to connect to instances

I would like  a way of running queries via SQL Server Management Studio from my local PC if that is at all possible.